# Iframe sometimes appears and will not dissapear

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, onload

I'm putting together [a quick webpage](http://roughgiraffed.com/spyboy/) for my friends band with multiple embeded youtube iframes that I want to be hidden at first (with jquery).

The issue is that often (on chrome/windows at least) the iframes will appear in the top left corner as though they were positioned absolutely to the top left.  In the javascript console I can then type `$("*").hide();` and everything will disappear but not the iframes.

[image]

The problem seems to be related to when I hide the iframes' containing divs (`$(".details").css("display","none");`).

Here is my code. Click the link above for the full working example.

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".details").css("display","none");
        $("a.date").click(function() { 

            $(this).parent().children("div").toggle('slow');
            $(document.body).animate({
                'scrollTop':   $(this).offset().top
            },   2000);
        }); 
    });
```

Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you fix the problem? Because I am not able to see what the issue is in the page you linked to. Viewed in both fox and chrome. The one thing I did notice is that the page took a long time to load.

Comment: nope, its still there... The loading time is probably because of the 9 youtube iframes I am opening up...

Comment: Works like a charm, or I've missed something. :S

Comment: Works fine here, on Arch Linux/Chromium.

Comment: Honestly I have no idea whats wrong. Though I will share some observations. If you expand each date one by one from top to bottom [without collapsing them back], then after a while you will see that page is displaying fine. Try rendering the page with only one video in each date div. That might give some clue...

Comment: Thanks everyone for checking this out.  I still haven't sorted out exactly whats going on, but I think I'll just change my approach, and dynamically load the videos as the dates are expanded

Answer (score 0):

Cant you lazy load iframe for each user click rather than pre-loading everything on page load?

Like binding the click listener on each link and setting the iframe src attribute to the corresponding youtube link?

Eg:

For the sake of this example, lemme assume that you have 10 youtube URLs and correspondingly 10 anchors in you html.

Rather than loading a separate iframe for each of the video, why dont you keep a single iframe whose src attribute which change depending on which link the user clicks.

```
$('a.youtubelinks').click(function(event){
    $('iframe').attr('src', $(event.target).attr('src'));
});
```

BONUS: You can programatically click the first link in your list so that the first video in the list will be set as ifram src

```
$('link1').click();
```